# importing font awesome to vue project

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vue-cli

i installed font-awesome into my Vue project exactly like in Docs but i got that error
[image]

first i installed it using these commands

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@prerelease
```

in main.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faUserSecret)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

Navbar.vue:

```
<div class="nav-icons">
    <font-awesome-icon icon="user-secret" />
</div>
```

Comment: it's only in the question here i edited it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using Vue 2 and the CLI, I recently built a Font Awesome test project that works.

IconList.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="icon-list">
    <h3>Icon List</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li v-for="(iconName, index) in currentIcons" :key="index" class="list-group-item" >
            <font-awesome-icon :icon="iconName" class="fa-2x" />
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button v-if="displayMoreBtn" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="showMore" >
          <font-awesome-icon icon="ellipsis-h" class="fa-2x" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faCoffee } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faCloudMoonRain } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faEnvelope } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faFan } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faEllipsisH } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faGuitar } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faPeace } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faRobot } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

library.add(faCoffee);
library.add(faCloudMoonRain);
library.add(faEnvelope);
library.add(faFan);
library.add(faEllipsisH);
library.add(faGuitar);
library.add(faPeace);
library.add(faRobot);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      initialIcons: ["coffee", "cloud-moon-rain", "envelope", "fan"],
      additionalIcons: ["guitar", "peace", "robot"],
      displayMoreBtn: true,
      currentIcons: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showMore() {
      this.currentIcons = this.currentIcons.concat(this.additionalIcons);
      this.displayMoreBtn = false;
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.currentIcons = this.initialIcons;
  },
};
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <icon-list />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import IconList from '@/components/stackoverflow/font-awesome-list/IconList'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      IconList
    },
  }
</script>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

// Font Awesome
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```